# Using PowerShell to process a JSON string

Tags: json, powershell

Suppose I have a piece of JSON in a PowerShell string, e.g.

```
$s = '{"foo":"hello"}'
```

My goal is to turn this into an object that I can manipulate (e.g. changing/adding properties), and then convert back to a json string.

So trying the obvious, I write:

```
$o = $s | ConvertFrom-Json    # convert the json string to an object
$o.foo = "hello2"             # change an existing prop
$o.bar = "World"              # add a new prop
$s2 = $o | ConvertTo-Json     # convert back into a json string
```

The problem is that the object I get back from `ConvertFrom-Json` is of type `PSCustomObject`, which doesn't allow adding properties. So the 3rd line blows up with:

`Exception setting "bar": "The property 'bar' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:1 char:1`

**Question:** what is the best way to approach this without bringing too much complexity?

Answer (score 9):

Custom objects **do** allow you to add properties, you just have to do it correctly. You need the Add-Member cmdlet.

```
$o = $s | ConvertFrom-Json    # convert the json string to an object
$o.foo = "hello2"             # change an existing prop
Add-Member -InputObject $o -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'bar' -Value "World"              # add a new prop
$s2 = $o | ConvertTo-Json     # convert back into a json string
```

It is worth noting that depending on your version of PowerShell that Add-Member line could be simplified to:

```
$o | Add-Member 'bar' 'World'
```

I'm not sure what version that syntax became acceptable, but I know it works in v4 and I think it works in v3.

Comment: Nice, the simpler `$o | Add-Member 'bar' 'World'` does work. Not as simple as a simple assignment, but good enough. Thanks!